# Create own ruleset for codesniffer PHPCS

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I am trying to create my own ruleset for PHPCS extending the WordPress standard.
My goal is to define that a opening brace starts as the same line as the function name.

```
    public function __construct() {

        self::$instance = $this;
    }
```

So I added this to my ruleset

```
    <rule ref="Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration">
        <properties>
            <property name="opening_brace" value="same"/>
            <property name="closing_brace" value="next_line"/>
            <severity>5</severity>
        </properties>
    </rule>
```

But the sniffer still shows me the error:

> Opening brace should be on a new line
> (Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.BraceOnSameLine)

I just found this codesnippet, but I have no idea how to find the correct propertynames.
How do I get the correct rule + property and value?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for now is to check the [source code](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/Functions/MultiLineFunctionDeclarationSniff.php) of sniffs to find out property names or just check the [docs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties). `Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration` doesn't have any properties to set so the code you proposed just won't work. You can use the following [sniff](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/Functions/OpeningFunctionBraceKernighanRitchieSniff.php) to achieve what you need ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style)).

```xml
<rule ref="Generic.Functions.OpeningFunctionBraceKernighanRitchie" />
```